# WSO2 ESB rewrites WSO2 Registry values on startup

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have the current installations of WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Registry (both 4.5.0).

Registry sharing is made exactly by the step by step [instruction](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html)

Then the usecase is the following:

1) add a zip containing WSDL/Schemas to the Governance Registry. Added them I case see in the registry bowser:

```
_system/governance/trunk
                        /endpoints
                        /schemas
                        /services
                        /wsdls
```

With all WSDL/Schemas/Endpoints/Services relevand to the just added WSDL package.

2) start WSO2 ESB ithe the following registry configuration:

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry_mounted">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https:localhost:9445/registry">
    <id>wso2_registry_mounted</id>
    <dbConfig>wso2registry_mounted</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/config">
    <instanceId>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/governance">
    <instanceId>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

3) Check registry browser both on ESB and Governance Registry. At least schemas folder content is gone overwritten by ESB.

Could anyone advise on how can I force ESB not to overwrite initial Registry entries. Marking mounted registry as readOnly=true - doesn't help.

Thanks,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `<mount overwrite="false"` not to be overwritten the content

Refer this [document](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance451/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details) for more details

Comment: Thanks, that helped to solve 75% of the problem. I realised that messed up mounting direction. Also I'd suggest that the default registry folder needs to be set to something other than /trynk/* as it's gets overwritten anyway. So I changed it to /repository/* and resources are not overwritten after that change.